# Median earth temperature development in 20th century

Tags: climate-change, global-weirding

Are there graphs with the median temperature development in the 20th century and if not, is there readily accessible data that can be used to calculate it?

Median is statistically more stable, at the same time I'd be curious to plot the variance as well. My suspicion is the median rises less steep than the average but at the same time the variance (or for that matter min/max) changes significantly as well.

Comment: Assuming a median could reasonably be calculated, it would flatten the curve and possibly eliminate an otherwise obvious trend. Extreme values are better preserved in the mean temperature, and they are important markers for a trend in the development.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you're saying temperature distribution may NOT be normally distributed, so mean and median may differ. Is that correct? Also, would you still geographically weight temperatures based on station clustering to find the median?

Comment: https://www.purplemath.com/modules/meanmode.htm

Comment: The median is robust and resistant, thus useful when data are not normal or when there are outliers. The spread affects median and mean identically as long as the distribution remains normal and the data clean. Do you have any evidence either of those assumptions do not hold for your input data?

Comment: I was just curious about using it since when doing statistics I (not a pro) usually saw differences. Maybe that's an interesting one to see "global weirding" @BarryCarter Temperature is capped from below, so it's perhaps the truncated normal distribution: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_normal_distribution

Comment: @BarryCarter Yes definitely, I'd like to use any existing method to weigh the input values

Comment: I'm guessing you've already seen http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/10154/sources-of-weather-data/10155 as a source of data, but I don't know if anyone has tried to compute median values.

Comment: @BarryCarter Cool thanks! That's certainly enough to get started